# How to print the Matrix(nrow x mcolumns) to ANDROID Screen?

Tags: java, android

I am having a java program which performs MATRIX ADDITION.I want to implement this to ANDROID.I have done layout also for this purpose.But how to implement this to android in such a way to get input from user and to print the output to mobile screen.I know that i cant use "System.out.print()" function here

Comment: I think you should check out the [Android Tutorials](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html).

Comment: You will need to run your App on a the Android Emulator (http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html) or if you have an Android device, this is even better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have very basic holes in knowledge in regards to android development, so as others have advised, you should check out http://developer.android.com/training/index.html. I will attempt to give you some start though, if you know general java programming, you can create an EditText view and then populate it as you would usually, but instead of using System.out.println(""); (if your EditText view is named editText1), use editText1.setText("");